# How to return an enum by item index as apposed to value index?

Tags: c++, enum-class

How do I index into an enum via "item index" instead of the "value indexing":

"Value indexing" (not useful to me with what I am doing):

```
eSerialBauds eBaud = static_cast<eSerialBauds>(1200); // yields eBaud1200
```

I want "item indexing": ( How to get the following? )

```
eSerialBauds eBaud = static_cast<eSerialBauds>(3); // to yield eBaud1200
```

---

```
// values (from WinBase.h)
#define CBR_110             110
#define CBR_300             300
#define CBR_600             600
#define CBR_1200            1200
#define CBR_2400            2400



enum class eSerialBauds
{
  eBaud110 = CBR_110,
  eBaud300 = CBR_300,
  eBaud600 = CBR_600,
  eBaud1200 = CBR_1200,
  eBaud2400 = CBR_2400,
}
```

---

Please note that I am given this enum class from another class.  There are many. So I have to work with what is given to me.

I did write a work around method but it would be nice to have a more elegant way of getting the result.

Comment: nvm I read too fast. I retract my duplicate vote. This is not [Conversion from int to enum class type possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148463/conversion-from-int-to-enum-class-type-possible)

Comment: Is my question clear enough for others?

Comment: I think so, I was just careless but left the comment so no one else votes it as a dup of that as well.

Comment: The target I used uses `enum` instead of `enum class`, but it's basically the same question. Just ping me if you think that's not an appropriate target.

Comment: The question was closed, but in case you want to keep the same syntax, you could do: https://replit.com/@Ranoiaetep/ExperiencedDeadTerabyte#main.cpp

Comment: @cigien which of the answers in the already answered solves the OP's problem?

Comment: @Surt That's irrelevant. If the questions are the same, then the question is a duplicate. Since an answer to the OP's question would work just fine on the target question, that's where an answer should be added (assuming it doesn't already exist).

Comment: The enumerations are used else where by others, that class is written.  I want to set the enumerations given a config file   I have a way around this, but would rather a more direct way using the enum class.

Comment: @cigien the answers there are only for contagious zero based enumerations which can't be used here, as the values are discontinuous, 110, 300, 600 etc.

Comment: @Surt Yes, I understand. But an answer that works for dicontiguous enumerations can be posted on the target question, and that is where the answer should go.

Comment: @cigen unlikely. The hard part of this question is that they are discontinuous. It being an `enum class` may very well lead to a different solution as well. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Just set up an array containing the enum values, like this:

```
static const eSerialBauds bauds_by_index [] = { eBaud110, eBaud300, eBaud600, eBaud1200, eBaud2400 };
```

And then you can do, for example:

```
eSerialBauds baud = bauds_by_index [3];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to build an array of the enum values.

```
static constexpr auto sBaudIndex = std::array{eBaud100, eBaud200, eBaud600, eBaud1200, eBaud2400);
```

Then you index that array. It is fragile, but I know of no way to have the compiler enumerate the enum values for you.

You could skip the `enum` if you don't need it, and just use the WinBase values in your array

Comment: `std::array` needs a template argument for the size, and you can make it `constexpr`.