# strongly typed enum from int . C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

We are recently converting all enum to class enum .

```
enum class Launches : std::uint32_t {
  D_FROM_FILE=0,
  D_FROM_FDISK,
  D_FROM_RDDISK,
  D_FROM_USB,
  D_FROM_UI,
  D_FROM_NET,
  D_FROM_DEFAULT
};

Launches  launches ;
```

I need to assign `launches` values based on int that i received from command line

This is what I am doing after conversion to strongly typed enum

```
if (receivedInt  == 1)
   launches = D_FROM_FDISK;
```

I want to avoid and do like

```
launches = receivedInt;
```

We fail to compile as this is what strongly typed `int` are supposed to do.

I want to avoid `if` and `switch` cases on `receivedInt`.

```
launches = (Launches)receivedInt ; // this compiles ..
```

but I am hesitant on this or on using `static_cast` ... whats the proper way ?

**using `static_cast` etc ? What benefit will remain on using strongly types enums then**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conversion from int to enum class type possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148463/conversion-from-int-to-enum-class-type-possible)

Comment: i saw that . But i am hesitent to use it because that defeats the purpose of strongly types enum

Comment: what benefit will remain of using a strongly typed enum then

Comment: The benefit will be that you can decide only to use it on initiation, and no implicit conversons will happen.

Comment: You cannot do this safely without a mapping function. Jut use a `switch` or a `std::map` and throw an exception on invalid values.

Comment: Isn't that ironic ? You want to enforce strong typing (for unsaid reasons), and the first thing you attempt is to work around it ! By the way, using an enum and letting the compiler assign the values while you receive an external value is calling for trouble.

Comment: *"using `static_cast` etc ? What benefit will remain on using strongly types enums then?"* The conversion is explicit now. (Most security might be bypassed anyway if really needed).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do typecasts you can use an unordered_map.
Here is an example that converts an int you could get from commandline into an enum value in a typesafe manner

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

enum class Launches 
{
    D_FROM_FILE = 0,
    D_FROM_FDISK,
    D_FROM_RDDISK,
    D_FROM_USB,
    D_FROM_UI,
    D_FROM_NET,
    D_FROM_DEFAULT
};

Launches get_option(const int option)
{
    static const std::unordered_map<int, Launches> launch_options
    {
        {1, Launches::D_FROM_FILE},
        {2, Launches::D_FROM_FDISK},
        //.. etc..
        {6, Launches::D_FROM_NET}
    };

    auto it = launch_options.find(option);
    if (it != launch_options.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    return Launches::D_FROM_DEFAULT;
}


int main()
{
    auto option = get_option(1);
    assert(option == Launches::D_FROM_FILE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The input is a received integer, not a string.

Comment: Ok changed example to int :)

Comment: `{1, Launches::D_FROM_FILE}` -> `{int{Launches::D_FROM_FILE}, Launches::D_FROM_FILE}` (and so that also fixes offset typo leading to wrong mapping).

Comment: Now, unless a supersmart compiler sees that the inputs form a contiguous sequence and implements like a switch, this is an horribly time- and space-inefficient solution.

Comment: That seems awfully error-prone in the long term. Any modifications to the enum have to be mirrored in the get_option function. This breaks the only change in one place rule of thumb.

Comment: Unordered maps aren't that inefficient O(1) lookup. This is one of those solutions that trades readability for a bit of performance. And unless you're running on a small processor shouldn't be an issue it's only called once. So it's engineering and thus a tradeoff.

Comment: Quoting O(1) lookup is the wrong way to look at this. Big O notation is used when you are thinking about large sets not small sets. The actual cost also includes a constant cost that depends on container type. For hash maps this constant time is large (but when the size n is large becomes irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

Stroustrup - The `enum` classes address three problems with conventional c++ enumerations:

- conventional enums **implicitly convert to int**;
- conventional enums **export their values to the surrounding scope**;
- the **underlying type** of conventional enum cannot be specified.

If you use `enum`s for IO, you will have to convert them at some point. Your `enum` is defined as a **continuous range**. You could add a `First` and a `Last` value and check the range ([demo](https://ideone.com/zyG0x5)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

enum class Launches : std::uint32_t
{
  First = 0,

  D_FROM_FILE = First,
  D_FROM_FDISK,
  D_FROM_RDDISK,
  D_FROM_USB,
  D_FROM_UI,
  D_FROM_NET,
  D_FROM_DEFAULT,

  Last = D_FROM_DEFAULT
};

template< typename E, typename T >
Launches seq_enum_cast(T  v)
{
  return v >= static_cast<T>(E::First) && v <= static_cast<T>(E::Last)
    ? static_cast<E>(v)
    : throw std::bad_cast();
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    auto a = seq_enum_cast<Launches>(1);
    std::cout << "a - success\n";
    auto b = seq_enum_cast<Launches>(-3); // fails
    std::cout << "b - success\n";
  }
  catch (const std::bad_cast& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what();
  }
}
```

If you are fine with defining an unused enumerator you could use the following definition (and change the validation accordingly) which seems to be **less error-prone**:

```
enum class Launches : std::uint32_t
{
  First = 0,

  D_FROM_FILE = First,
  //...
  D_FROM_DEFAULT,

  Last
};
```